# pdfbox unable to draw bezier curve

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using version 1.8 of pdfbox. I am trying to draw a curve on the page, I have some basic knowledge of how to draw it using control points. So I just tried drawing a basic curve but nothing is showing up.

I started with the following line of code:

```
stream.setNonStrokingColor(155);
stream.stroke();
stream.addBezier321(...);
stream.closeAndStroke();
```

Is ther something i'm missing? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Uhm - shouldn't you set the stroking color? Also, please post more code (i.e. you creating the document, the content stream, the page), and do also draw an ordinary line. Just to see if anything appears. The "stroke()" command doesn't make any sense if no curve exists. And where's the initial move?

Comment: I have all the page set up, I have been able to draw a whole rectangle with lines and fill it with color. Now I'm trying my hand at the bezier curve. I thought we have to call stream.stroke() first. Then add the curves and finally, call stream.closeAndStroke(); My initial move was going to be addBezier321(). So I start from some position and give it the final point and a control point to draw the curve with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't try to test what exactly was wrong with your example (see my comment below your question, but there might be other causes too), but here's some code that does what you need:

```
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    PDPage pdpage = new PDPage();
    doc.addPage(pdpage);
    PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, pdpage, false, false);

    // move stuff a bit up and right
    stream.concatenate2CTM(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(100, 400));

    stream.setStrokingColorSpace(PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);
    stream.setStrokingColor(Color.red);
    stream.setLineWidth(10f);
    stream.moveTo(1, 1);
    stream.addBezier32(111, 075, 200, 200);
    stream.addBezier32(352, 124, 80, 80);
    stream.addBezier32(432, 333, 300, 333);
    stream.stroke();

    stream.close();
    doc.save(filename);
    doc.close();
```

[image]

More advanced stuff: to to fill what you get, use this code:

```
    // move stuff a bit up
    stream.concatenate2CTM(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(100, 400));

    stream.setStrokingColorSpace(PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);
    stream.setStrokingColor(Color.red);
    stream.setNonStrokingColorSpace(PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);
    stream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.blue);

    stream.setLineWidth(10f);
    stream.moveTo(1, 1);
    stream.addBezier32(111, 075, 200, 200);
    stream.addBezier32(352, 124, 80, 80);
    stream.addBezier32(432, 333, 300, 333);
    stream.addBezier32(234, 129, 200, 300);
    stream.closeSubPath();
    stream.appendRawCommands("\nB*\n"); // Fill and then stroke the path, using the even-odd rule
    // to use the nonzero winding number rule, use "B" instead of "B*"
```

To learn more about the operators B and B*, read the [PDF specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), and start at "operator summary".

and the result is:
[image]

Comment: Great. Thanks. I guess I had to call stroke() at the end.

Comment: I have one other question. I need to make an ellipse, once I draw it, how do I fill it with a solid colour?

Also, what is the difference between addBezier32() and addBezier31()?

Comment: use fill() . Don't forget to select a non stroking color. I will try to improve my example so that there is something to fill.

Comment: Thank you Tilman. I can't seem to figure out the difference between addBezier32() and addBezier31()? Docs aren't much helpful as well.

Comment: Re the different addBezier calls, I recommend that you read the API doc and the PDF specification (8.5.2.2 Cubic Bézier Curves). There is some math involved. http://www.verypdf.com/document/pdf-format-reference/pg_0227.htm

Comment: Thank you so much, Tilman! This is some pretty neat stuff we can do with Bezier curves. I've read parts of the pdf specification when I was creating a rectangle. I'll read more about the operators you mentioned above. Thanks again!